# Scraping with Beautiful Soup and Python KeyError: 'href'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am getting `KeyError: 'href'`. I gather this is because my attribute is not defined, I have tried to find a solution, however have been unsuccessful so far. My code as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_url = "https://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/"
re = requests.get(main_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text, "html.parser")
city_tags = soup.find_all('h2', class_="title")  # The section containing the links to the cities
cities_links = [main_url + tag['href'] for tag in city_tags]  # Iterates through city_tags and stores them in a [list]
```

Error occurs when calling `cities_links`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_url = "http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury"
re = requests.get(main_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text, "html.parser")
city_tags = soup.find_all('h2', class_="title")
cities_links = [main_url + tag.find('a').get('href','') if tag.find('a') else '' for tag in city_tags]
print cities_links
```

This will result :

```
[u'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/bronze-en-suite/', u'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/silver-en-suite/', u'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/bronze-studio/', u'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/bronze-premium-studio/', u'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/silver-studio/', u'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/gold-studio/', u'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/platinum-studio/', u'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/two-bed-flat/', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Alternatively, you can use **lxml** module which is order of magnitude faster than **BeautifulSoup** :

```
import requests
from lxml import html

main_url = "http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury"
re = requests.get(main_url)
root = html.fromstring(re.content)
cities_links = [main_url + link for link in root.xpath('//h2[@class="title"]/a/@href')]
print cities_links
```

This will result in :

```
['http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/bronze-en-suite/', 'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/silver-en-suite/', 'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/bronze-studio/', 'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/bronze-premium-studio/', 'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/silver-studio/', 'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/gold-studio/', 'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/platinum-studio/', 'http://www.chapter-living.com/properties/highbury/properties/highbury/rooms/two-bed-flat/']
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`h2` tags don't have `href` attribute. That belongs to `a` tags. That's why you're getting this error, you're trying to access an attribute that doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that. Where would you say they are stored...?

Comment: I would say they are stored in the `a` tag. That's why the response above is doing `tag.find('a')`, because `h2` tags don't have an `href` attribute.